# React hooks setState possible bug in try catch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I have a function to handle the submission of a login form and something really strange is happening.
If I enter all the field correctly at the first try everything works fine but if I trigger an error then every time that I run the function error will always be true even setting it as false in the start of the function.

```
const initialState = {
email: '',
password: '',
error: false,
success: false
};
const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

const handleSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault();
setState({ ...state, error: false, success: false });

props.form.validateFields(async (err, values) => {
  try {
    const { data, status } = await axios.post(vManager.path, values);

    if (data.token) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
    }

    setState({ ...state, success: true });
  } catch (err) {
    setState({ ...state, error: true });
  }
});
```

};

Comment: I'm not totally sure on this, but in the hooks documentation, they have the `setState` written like `setState(state => ({ ...state, etc...}) )` so I'm just wondering if you added the `state =>` if that would affect it

Comment: Yes! that works

Comment: Oh great! I'm still fairly new to the nuances of `react-hooks` so I wasn't sure if it could be done that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing a `state =>` inside the `setState` hook.

```
setState(state => ({ ...state, error: false, success: false }));
```

[Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables)

Comment: Consider replying in more informative way and quoting the relating piece from the resource, rather than simply linking it.

Comment: @jayarjo I would've except the documentation on it is not as verbose as I would've liked. The only reason I suspected this was the answer was because of the coded examples they had in the docs. There's no mention of the reason why a function needs to be passed in it. At least none that I've found yet.

Comment: The ability to pass in the function is useful when you need to update the state from inside the closure (happens if you need to set timeouts in useEffect for example). That way you will still get the actual state value instead of the stale one.

Answer (score 0):

The solution presented by @Keno Clayton works.
And then I found the explanation on React documentation

> state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from state and props. For instance, suppose we wanted to increment a value in state by props.step:

Comment: If @keno-clayton has helped you to solve your problem, you should upvote his answer and maybe even mark it as a correct one.